# ionic responsive page with imageMapResize

Tags: ionic-framework

I have small problem with ionic framework.
I want to create page with responsive image as background, on every "button" on image I would like to create button from ionic.Image map on html and javascript
This is done using `imageMapResize()` plugin from node, and actualy working great.

What is the problem, this thing must be only on first page, and working after code is run for first time, but when you get back from other pages to first page, not working.

I tried:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    imageMapResize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ionViewDidEnter()` , this method is called every time you enter the page.
You can call `ionViewWillEnter()`  before you enter the page if you want.

Comment: Can you try this `this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);` it will reload the page.

Comment: You can put it on the fonction i give you below , better on the ionViewWillEnter()

Comment: ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
  }

  
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    imageMapResize();
   
} if I put on this way imagemapresize not working :(

Comment: Try to see if you enter on the fonction imageresize when you back. Maybe its just dont enter.

Comment: when I put on this way,  loaded is contantly on console log   ionViewWillEnter() {
    imageMapResize();
    console.log("loaded");
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
}

Comment: Can you try to put your function `imageMapResize()` on the constructor ? Or just after the platform is ready

Comment: i tried this : platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      console.log('Platform is ready');
      imageMapResize();
      }); not working...

Comment: Did you keep your onViewWillEnter function ?

Comment: noup...i tried now with this and still not working, in answer you could check full code

Comment: ionViewWillEnter() { imageMapResize();   }   platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      console.log('Platform is ready');
      imageMapResize();
      });

   
  }

Comment: Try this  (full code) :  `ionViewWillEnter() { console.log("loaded"); this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component); }`  and after the platform is ready you call resizeimage();

Comment: noup still not working, after this I was unable to return to home page.

Comment: Actually  i don't see any solution, maybe its your resizeimage function which has a problem.